# How to stop collision when hidden

Tags: objective-c, collision-detection

I'm aware that this question has been asked before, but there was no answer.

I have objects which are linked with the player using the following code:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Player.frame, obstacle.frame)) {
    [self finish];
    // later on in the code i then hide the obstacle

    obstacle.hidden = YES;
}
```

but when the object is hidden it still detects a collision is there away to remove collision when the object is hidden ?

Comment: Can you move the code that detects the collision to a point after you hide the object?

Comment: Or add some "is object not hidden" logic to your `if` statement.

Comment: perhaps if your obstacle is an array object you could use `[array removeAllObjects];` or assign `obstacle = NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to provide more Information but why don't you check whether the obstacle is hidden before you execute the collision-code?

```
if (obstacle.hidden != YES) {
  // collision-code
}
```

Comment: You should not check variables explicitly against the values `YES` and `NO`.  Use `if (obstacle.hidden)` or `if (!obstacle.hidden)` instead.  If, for some reason, someone sets a BOOL with a different value other than `YES` and `NO`, then neither `value == YES` nor `value == NO` would evaluate as true.

Comment: when you're in Objective-C, you should set it to YES or NO.

Comment: Indeed... you should set BOOL variables to YES and NO... but you should not check them against YES and NO.  A BOOL is not a pure binary variable.  It uses a C type that actually has 256 different values.  One of those values (zero) evaluates to "false" and all the rest evaluate to "true."  While comparing with NO is not a big deal, comparing against YES will only be right for one of the 255 possible "true" values.